# Lubuntu Desktop messed up for logged in user, but not for guest

Tags: lubuntu

I recently upgraded my laptop from Lubuntu 12.04 to 14.04.1 and the upgrade process seemed to go fine.

However, when I went to login as my normal user, I encountered an issue. The background loaded up, but none of LXDE or LXPanel showed up, leaving me with an empty desktop and nothing else except two errors.

I thought that this was weird, so I just figured something had been messed up and would be fixed by a reboot. But it wasn't. I then tried logging in as guest, and it's just fine. I checked the `~/.xsession-errors` file (for my main user, not guest, did it via `TTY1`) and this is what I got:

```
Script for ibus started at run_im.
Script for auto started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
init: Unable to register as subreaper: Invalid argument
init: lxsession main process (1649) killed by TERM signal
init: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
init: job dbus failed to stop
init: job upstart-dbus-session-bridge failed to stop
init: job upstart-dbus-system-bridge failed to stop
init: job upstart-file-bridge failed to stop
```

I also read the sometimes removing the ~/.Xauthority file can help, if the ownership is messed up. `ls -l /home/MYUSER/.Xauthority` tells me `-rw------- 1 MYUSER MYUSER 60 Aug 16 09:57 /home/MYUSER/.Xauthority`. Should that be root or something else, or should I try deleting that and `~/.profile`.

Here's what `~/.profile` looks like:

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Should I post the output of `dmesg`?

I'll try and get a screenshot, but does anyone have any idea what could be causing the desktop (LXDE/LXPanel) not to display?

**EDIT** I attempted removing the ~/.XAuthority file, but that didn't seem to do anything.

**EDIT** I have uploaded the contents of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` as it appeared right after a boot and login to the guest account to [Ubuntu Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8143583/) as requested by Braiam.

Comment: What's the content of `~/.xsession-errors`?

Comment: @Braiam I mentioned it in the post, towards the top: "I checked the ~/.xsession-errors file (for my main user, not guest, did it via TTY1) and this is what I got:..."

Comment: Sorry, I meant `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

Comment: Sorry about the delay @Braiam. I've been busy recently with Driver's Ed and other things and haven't had time to use Stack Exchange, let alone work on fixing an old computer. I've updated the question with a link to an Ubuntu Pastebin with the file in it.

Comment: @Braiam Did you ever look at the Ubuntu Paste?

Comment: According to your logs, there isn't anything wrong. (unless you are showing the wrong logs.)

Comment: @Braiam So, does this mean it's an issue with configuration files? I've heard the Xorg sometimes doesn't auto-configurate correctly in 14.04 PPC, so I'm going to investigate that. Here's a newer /var/Xorg.0.log, since I've deleted `~/.Xauthority` and `/etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu` and rebooting: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8319281/.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem after upgrade. Here is a somewhat inelegant solution: removing the files in /etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu and rebooting. This seemed to work for me.